# `EditText` won't adjust its position and `ToolBar` content will disappear when keyboard pops up

Tags: android

I am trying to make a instant chat interface.

Normal:
[image]

But when I click the EditText, the keyboard will pop up but EditText won't be pushed up along with keyboard, also, contents in ToolBar will disappear. 
Like this:
[image]

I tried setting `android:windowSoftInputMode` but problem still exists. I think the problem may due to the xml file structure.
Here's my xml file structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout >
      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar >
        <TextView />
      </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView />
        <com.loopeer.shadow.ShadowView>
            <LinearLayout>
                <ImageView/>
                <EditText/>
                <ImageView />
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.loopeer.shadow.ShadowView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Shadow View provides shadow effect like CardView. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample chat ui layout it should work pretty well:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvcommlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_above="@+id/view">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <!-- A horizontal line between the chatbox and RecyclerView -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#dfdfdf"
            android:layout_above="@+id/layout_chatbox"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_chatbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tvcomm"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="Enter message"
                android:maxLines="6" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/comment"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SEND"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```